# Combining two arrays via the sum of two fields Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Looking for general advice on approaches here. Description and pseudocode below:

Array1 has 100 objects type integer
Array2 has 100 objects type integer

Create Array 3 10,000 objects summing the two arrays

```
Array3.1 = Array1.[Field1] from 1 to 100 + Array2.1.[Field1]
Array3.2 = Array1.[Field1] from 1 to 100 + Array2.2.[Field1]
Array3.3 = Array1.[Field1] from 1 to 100 + Array2.3.[Field1]
……
Array3.100 = Array1.[Field1] from 1 to 100 + Array2.100.[Field1]
```

Challenges:
Not sure how to easily reference the field within an object in the array. I can pull up the object line but this returns the entire object whereas I only want to pull one field. This would be helpful beyond this particular question.

Not sure about the best method to create the new array, whether it should be a loop or something else.

Further background
The final objective will be to create an output that compares the sum of the specific field for every pair within the two arrays to find and then rank them from best to worst.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that difficult.

Every entry in the resulting array is just the 2nd array with the value at the current index of the first array added to it.

```js
const a1 = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20];
const a2 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8];

const result = a1.map(x => a2.map(y => x + y));

console.log(result);
```

If you don't want the resulting array to nested, use `flatMap`:

```js
const a1 = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20];
const a2 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8];

const result = a1.flatMap(x => a2.map(y => x + y));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear, and I appreciate the reply.

I'm stuck on the reference to a specific field within the object in the array, whereas in your examples you are using a single field in the array. For example:

const a1 = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20];
const a2 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8];

My a1 would be: 
[0] 0, 10, ab,
[1] 5, 2, xy,
[2] 10, 22, ls,
[3] 15, 2, tt,
[4] 20, 12, kf

And rather than run the equation on just the first number 0,5,10,15,20 I wanted to target a different field in the object within the array, IE in my a1 I wanted to point the equation to 10, 2, 22,2, 12.